# I keep getting a Server Error 500 while trying to submit a registration form on my laravel app hosted on aws

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, forge

I just hosted my new Laravel website on an Amazon EC2 instance using Laravel Forge. I happen to have a register form on my website but upon submission it it saves the records in my database and displays a `500 server error`. I use PHP version 7.3 and MySQL version 5.7 and Laravel version 5.8

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43833932/laravel-passport-500-internal-server-error-on-ec2 maybe permission for storage

Comment: how do i sort out the storage permission issues and where do i sort it out

Comment: https://medium.com/devopslinks/deploying-and-scaling-a-laravel-app-on-aws-1349dcd7d17a

Comment: i would make it 775 for the folders

Comment: where do i do that? I dont know what file to make the changes or how to get there

Comment: sorry to ask but are you the owner of the site or a developer ?

Comment: I am both the owner and the developer but its my first time with laravel and forge and aws ec2

Comment: you should read more on laravel and forge i think forge give you shh access that you can run commands on your server

Comment: i have already ssh into my server, all i need to know is what to do on it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel-5-and-others take a read

Comment: I still have this issue

Comment: this is what i have in my logs

Comment: #76 /home/forge/onenaira.com.ng/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#77 /home/forge/onenaira.com.ng/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#78 {main}
"}

Comment: what the error says ? in the log

Comment: #76 /home/forge/onenaira.com.ng/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request)) #77 /home/forge/onenaira.com.ng/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request)) #78 {main} "}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54449639/how-to-debug-laravel-site-show-http-error-500 he had same issue